# Ion-refresher does not reload data properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app, which loads data from JSON file. When `onRefresh()` function is triggered, it loads data from second JSON file instead. Everything works fine, but clicking the elements, generated from the second JSON file do not load the proper data.

So using `href="#/tab/chats/{{item._id}}`, before `Refresh()` works perfectly, but using it after, gives no results. Here are parts of the code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Schedule">
    <ion-content ng-controller="ScheduleController">
        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh" on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in schedule.programmeField" class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/tab/chats/{{item._id}}">
                <img ng-src="http://###/w200/{{item._photos[0]._id}}.jpg" alt="No Image" class="padding-vertical">
                <p>{{item.startField.slice(8,10) + ":" + item.startField.slice(10,12)}}</p>
                <h2>{{item.titleField[0].valueField}}</h2>
                <p>{{item.descField[0].valueField}}</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

```
.controller("ScheduleController", ["$scope", "$http", "$state",   "$stateParams", function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
    $http.get('../downloads/bbtv.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.schedule = data;
        $scope.whichelement = $stateParams.aId;
        console.log($scope.whichelement);
        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            $http.get('../downloads/bbtv2.json').success(function (data) {
                $scope.schedule = data;                 
                $scope.whichelement = $stateParams.aId;
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                console.log($scope.whichelement);
            });
        }
    });
}])

.state('tab.chat-detail', {
    url: '/chats/:aId',
    views: {
        'tab-chats': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
            controller: 'ScheduleController'
        }
    }
})
```

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-view>
        <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ScheduleController">
            <ion-list class="list-inset">
                <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in schedule.programmeField | filter: { _id: whichelement}">
                    <img ng-src="http://photos.media-press.tv/w200/{{item._photos[0]._id}}.jpg" alt="No Image" class="padding-vertical">
                    <h2>{{item.titleField[0].valueField}}</h2>
                    <p>{{item.descField[0].valueField}}</p>                        
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-pane>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have nested the two GET calls? Seems like the doRefresh method should be in the main controller closure rather than nested.

Comment: You are right! Did not notice it.. but It did not fix my issue.